# Andengine Box2D Physics "disappearing"?

Tags: box2d, andengine

I have problems with my PhysicsWorld in Andengine GLES20. Sometimes when i first load my app and level there is no velocity added to my bodies. they also rotate slower as it seems. This also happens in Game when I press the home button and then go back into the app. 
Any ideas? Is this fixed in the AnchorCenter Branch?

Comment: I had similar problem, when I was registering the physics world as update handler more than once (typically onPause/onResume)

Comment: it seems for me that onPause and onResume caused this problem for me too